# Can I tell what version of SharePoint is being used from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have some static JavaScript being rendered to a page and would like it to behave differently if the version of SharePoint it is being displayed by is 2013. Can I tell what version of SharePoint is being used?

The reason behind this request is related to the introduction of the `15` subfolder under `/_layouts`.

I cannot modify the output JS from the server side as the it is included in a Custom Field Type's `fldtypes*.xml`.

Comment: Could you use the native DOM element _spPageContextInfo.webUIVersion? If it's 4 then you're on 2010, assuming 2013 is 5, and nonexistant in 2007 or 3.

Comment: @PirateEric: Good call! Although presumably it would be set to 3 if the 2007 site/list had been migrated but not upgraded, and 4 in 2013 when in "14 mode" (although that may not be disagreeable).

Comment: Ya I'm not sure exactly how it would return in an old environment and a 2013 one, don't have access to either of those at the moment.

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.webUIVersion returns "15" on a freshly-installed 2013 environment. @Eric, you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a native DOM element called _spPageContextInfo.webUIVersion that you could use. In SP 2010, it will return 4. Derek confirmed this is in 2013 and returns 15. 2007 might not return anything or throw undefined. This should allow you to determine where you need to refer to in your script.

Comment: You should consider that `_spPageContextInfo.webUIVersion` will only return the **UI** version currently being used. It will return 4 even if it is a SP 2013 site running in the SP 2010 UI.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the Client Object Model for this:

```
var clientContext;
// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    //here you get the version
    var serverVersion = clientContext.get_serverVersion();
}
```

[Here the reference from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj247006.aspx)

Comment: That's an intriguing method. It'd mean making a second call to SharePoint on each page load and some extra checks for 2007, but it's certainly an avenue I hadn't considered.

Comment: @StuartPegg maybe store the result in a cookie or local  storage

Comment: @axrwkr: That would help, but Eric's solution won me over with its simplicity.

Comment: @StuartPegg: you're right :)

Comment: @StuartPegg I believe this is the answer which will return 100% of the time the correct server version. The other two answers will give you the current **UI** version.

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande That's true about the UI version (as I noted in the question comments). Eric's is the one I used, as returning `14` in "14 mode" works out pretty well for my purposes. I avoided this option because of the extra call overhead and the requirement that the user has COM enabled (if there're not on 2007, obviously).

Answer (score 5):

Two great answers above... I recently (like a few days ago) put the following together:

```
getSPVersion = function(returnExternal) {

    var versionMap = {
                        12: '2007',
                        14: '2010',
                        15: '2013'
                },
        version     = (typeof SP !== 'undefined')
                    ?   parseInt(SP.ClientSchemaVersions.currentVersion) 
                    :   12;

    if (returnExternal) {

        version = versionMap[version] || version;

    }

    return version

}
```

Figure I would share.

Comment: SP.ClientSchemaVersions will return you the **UI** version being used currently. It will return 14.0.0.0 even if it is a SP 2013 site running in the SP 2010 UI

Comment: Did not know that.   Thank you for commenting. I may have to change my function to one of the suggestions above. In my case, I was trying to determine the capabilities available client side, so it may still be vid for my use case.

Comment: That last sentence was suppose to be: "still be valid for my use case."  Thanks again

Comment: Also, O365 might give v16. They are with the step ahead.

Comment: I tried on O365 Sharepoint (in admin center) and got `15`, but get `14` for my on-premise 2010.

Comment: @BGM - that sounds correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach how to determine SharePoint version from JavaScript:

```
function getVersion(webUrl,complete)
{
    $.ajax({
       url: webUrl + "/_vti_pvt/service.cnf",
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(result) {
          var lines = result.trim().split('\n');
          if(lines.length == 2) {
              var versionProperty = lines[1].split('|');
              complete(versionProperty.length == 2 ? versionProperty[1] : null);
          }
          else {
              complete(null);   
          }        
       }
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
getVersion(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
   function(version){
       console.log(version); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work rather well, although it can be a little slow to return the value on O365.  I get the right versions on both 2010 and O365.  [But the credit goes here](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-how-to-get-sharepoint.html), and they have several other options that also work.

```
var xmlHttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {   // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, and so on: Use native object.    
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6.
  }
}

xmlHttp.open('HEAD', location.href, false);
xmlHttp.send();
var headers =  xmlHttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
var SPVersion = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices");

console.log("Full Sharepoint Version ="+SPVersion);
switch(SPVersion.substring(0,2) ){
  case "12": console.log("2007"); break;
  case "14": console.log("2010"); break;
  case "16": console.log("2013"); break;  
  default: console.log(SPVersion); break;
}
```

I like this way [Again, the credit goes here](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-how-to-get-sharepoint.html):

```
//return 0 if not Sharepoint, otherwise, return major version
function getSharePointMajorVersion(){
 // The following copied from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx
  var xmlHttp = null;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, and so on: Use native object.
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
       // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6.
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open('HEAD', location.href, false);
  xmlHttp.send();
  var SPVersion = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices");
  if(SPVersion == null){
    return 0;
  }else{
    return  SPVersion.substring(0,2);
  }
}

alert( getSharePointMajorVersion() );
```