# Detect SharePoint version from JavaScript ( 2013 / 2016 or Office365 )

Tags: 2013, javascript, office-365, 2016

I have a javascript code that will run on different SharePoint platforms ( Office365, SharePoint 2013 & SharePoint 2016 )

I would like to detect the environment my code is running on, so I can add some CSS classes to control page behvaior based on the environment that I am running on.

How can I detect all those environment, note that code should still work if page is accessed anonymously ( `SP.ClientContext` is not an option here )

something like:

```
if ( isSharePoint2013() ) {
  document.documentElement.className += ' sharepoint-2013';
} else if ( isSharePoint2016() ) {
  document.documentElement.className += ' sharepoint-2016';
} else if ( isOffice365() ) {
  document.documentElement.className += ' office-365';
}
```

so what could be the logic behind those detection methods, in order to detect the right platform type ?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74978/can-i-tell-what-version-of-sharepoint-is-being-used-from-javascript

Comment: have you tried the mbauer's code?it give the server version not UR

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP all of the answers in your posted link, are using the same technique by detecting the UI version of the platform, unfortunately, UI version is the same for all 2013, 2016 & Office365 which is **15**

Answer (score 2):

This code will work anonymously if you uncheck [Remote Interfaces permission](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e752b077-48d8-4d66-a5d8-60f34e9b285d/enable-anonymous-access-for-javascript-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

```
 var clientContext;
// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    //here you get the version
    console.log(clientContext.get_serverVersion());
}
function onRequestFailed(){
    console.log("Failed!");   
}
```

Comment: Having to wait for an async response to complete, will affect the overall user experience, as you can see I need to add classes as soon as possible.

Comment: for o365, you could say `if(window.location.href.indexOf("sharepoint.com") > 0){ //its o365}`

Comment: thanks, but it won't work if client has registered a custom domain

Comment: theres also a `_spPageContextInfo.tenantAppVersion` will be "0" if it's not hosted in the cloud.

Comment: @AnasNakawa SharePoint online will always have sharepoint.com in it's URL no matter wheather you registered your domain or not

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.tenantAppVersion gives "2537066992" in 2019 on-premise. "window.location.href.indexOf("sharepoint.com") > 0" - is only working method for now, I think. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

JSOM requires SP.js, so you can not check for version info early on in the Browser.

This is a snippet of the REST call I use to monitor SPOnline progress

```
fetch('/_vti_pvt/buildversion.cnf', {
    headers: new Headers({"content-type": "text/plain"})
}).then(function (r) {
    return r.text();
}).then(function (buildtext) {
    var build = buildtext.split('vti_buildversion:SR|')[1].split('\n')[0];
    console.info('SharePoint build:',build);
}).catch(function(e){
    console.error(,e);
});
```

This outputs **16.0.6008.1203** on one of my SPOnline tenants today
*note: This changes weekly, sometimes hourly, and I even see Microsoft retract versions*

On-Prem this version will only change on updates.
BUT read this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/

Since I only monitor SPOnlines deltas I don't care about what the Buildversion is.

The fetch API (http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) is standard in Chrome,
for IE you need the PolyFill: https://github.com/github/fetch